# Расстояние между прямыми

Tags: python

Как получить угол между двумя линиями на графике? Шкала значения не имеет, т.к. полагаю что какие бы то ни было углы все равно будут на одном графике соотносится правильно.

В списке `y` значения графика.
`y = [5.6, 6.9, 6.1, 5.5, 5.6, 6.9, 6.1, 5.5]`
Ему соответствует список `chouse` заполнен 0-ми, а там где стоит 1 - означает конец линии из графика y, которое будем сравнивать со следующим.
`chouse = [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0]`

К примеру. Первая 1 стоит на 6.9. Сравнивать будем угол между линией 5.6-6.9 и следующую 6.9-6.1. То есть от начала и до конца линию "рисуем" в уме и сравниваем потом. Второй 1 соответственно сравнивает линию 5.5-5.6 и   5.6-6.9.

Вот пример какие углы пытаюсь найти:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, как-то так должно быть. Углы не соответствуют тому, что видно на вашем графике, потому что у вас масштабы осей разные. Для проверки что всё правильно, я подкрасил участвующие в расчёте отрезки и нарисовал точку в месте их соединения.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

def angle_between(v1, v2):
    return np.degrees(np.arccos(np.dot(v1, v2) /
        (np.linalg.norm(v1) * np.linalg.norm(v2))))

y = [5.6, 6.9, 6.1, 5.5, 5.6, 6.9, 6.1, 5.5]
chouse = [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0]

sns.lineplot(x = range(len(y)), y = y)

for i, f in enumerate(chouse):
    if not f:
        continue
    x11 = i
    x12 = i - 1
    y11 = y[x11]
    y12 = y[x12]
    x21 = i
    x22 = i + 1
    y21 = y[x21]
    y22 = y[x22]
    v1 = np.array([x12 - x11, y12 - y11])
    v2 = np.array([x22 - x21, y22 - y21])
    plt.plot([x11, x12], [y11, y12], 'g-')
    plt.plot([x11], [y11], 'b*')
    plt.plot([x21, x22], [y21, y22], 'g-')
    plt.plot([x21], [y21], 'b*')
    plt.plot([x12, x22], [y12, y22], 'b--')
    print(angle_between(v1, v2))

plt.ylim((3, 8)) # выравниваем масштаб осей!
```

Вывод:

```
88.90878377473736
133.2791851663271
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По дополнительной просьбе: проверяйте, что оба вектора по оси `y` имеют один знак, проще всего для этого их перемножить и проверить, что получилось положительное число. Только изменённый фрагмент:

```py
    angle = angle_between(v1, v2)
    if (y12 - y11) * (y22 - y21) > 0:
        angle = -angle
    print(angle)
```

Вывод:

```
-88.90878377473736
133.2791851663271
```

Comment: Ну тогда надо передавать в отрисовку именованные аргументы x = ..., y = ... а не просто данные.

Comment: Поправил код, чтобы не было предупреждения